# Validate Email format PHP

Tags: php, mysql, email, verification

This is a snippet of a user invite code. The code should get the email address from the previous POST form and then check whether it is in the correct format. I used a function called checkMail to do the work. However, it seems like whenever the email is in the wrong format or when the form was left blank it never shows this line:

```
else if(checkEmail($_POST['email'])==false){ 'Whoops! Looks like the email address you selected is invalid :('; }
```

or

```
else { 'Whoops! It looks like you didn&#39;t actually add an email address...'; }
```

Have been stuck for hours, trying to debug... hopefully someone here can help me out!!

Here is the full code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
        if(checkEmail($_POST['email'])==true) {
            $thisDomain = str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
            $mailcont = "Someone has invited you to an invite only website!\nYour invite code is: ".$_POST['code'].".\n\nYou can use it at http://".$thisDomain."?go=register&hash=".$_POST['code'];
            if(sendEmail($_POST['email'],'You have been invited!',$mailcont,'noreply@'.$thisDomain)) {
                echo 'Your invite was dispatched to '.$_POST['email'].'<br /><br />Go back <a href="?go=home">home</a>';
            } else { echo 'Whoops! Something went horribly wrong, and we couldn&#39;t send the email :('; }
        } else if(checkEmail($_POST['email'])==false){ 'Whoops! Looks like the email address you selected is invalid :('; }
    } else { 'Whoops! It looks like you didn&#39;t actually add an email address...'; }
break;
```

Here is the code for the function checkMail:

```
function checkEmail($email) 
   /**
Validate an email address.
Provide email address (raw input)
Returns true if the email address has the email 
address format and the domain exists.
*/
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if
(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless 
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || 
 checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys. You guys are awesome, I am new to stackoverflow but I find myself coming back here everyday for ideas and for the great help from the community!

Comment: You really should be using [`filter_var()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for this. `filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: Do you know whether checkemail() is returning the expected result? If not, the conditional block is irrelevant and the problem is in the function; if it is returning the correct result then it's the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`else { 'Whoops! It looks like you didn&#39;t actually add an email address...'; }`
should be
`else { echo 'Whoops! It looks like you didn&#39;t actually add an email address...'; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter way to check the email address.

```
<?php
$re1='.*?'; //Non-greedy match on filler
$re2='([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})'; //Email Address 1
if ($c=preg_match_all ('/'.$re1.$re2.'/is', $text, $matches)) {
    $email=$matches[1][0];
}
?>
```

`$email` will either contain the email inside `$text` or nothing. You can check with `empty()` later on. Domain validation is in my opinion meaningless. You can say all the funny impressive things you want, I have yet to see a real-world situation where a check like this would be a necessity.

Comment: @ColeJohnson `filter_var` is new from PHP5. I'm old-school from a PHP3 background ahah. Thanks for the tip!